# Is it possible to combine a pivot/transform query with another table (to add an additional column of data)?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, odbc

I have a relatively simple pivot/transform query, which appears as follows:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(T1.VALUE) As SumOfVal
SELECT    T1.DATE, T1.HOUR
FROM      T1
WHERE     (T1.DATE = #1/1/2010#)          AND
          (T1.NAME IN ("name1", "name2")) AND
          (T1.TYPE IN ("type1", "type2"))
GROUP BY  T1.DATE, T1.HOUR
PIVOT     T1.NAME + " " + T1.TYPE
```

Which returns me something like this:

```
  DATE   | HOUR | name1 type1 | name1 type2 | name2 type1 | name2 type2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/2010 |   1  |    222.22   |   123.11    |   1241.23   |   133124
1/1/2010 |   2  |    252.22   |   121.11    |    121.23   |   122150
```

And so on.  Now, in another table (with a similar layout), I have more readings which I want to join to the end of the query as another column.  The `DATE` and `HOUR` will match up exactly, and I can manually specifiy *which* name/type to use from the table.

Where I'm stuck is, how would I add this into the query?  I tried to `INNER JOIN` the two tables in the `FROM` clause, and then added the column name to the `SELECT` clause, but it complained that the field name was not part of the aggregate function.  I also tried to add it to the `TRANSFORM` clause (and the `PIVOT` clause), but I don't think you can specify multiple fields for them.

Is this possible to do in a single query using SQL, or do I need to perform both queries separately?

---

One last note - the query still works after I `INNER JOIN` table `T1` with `T2` on the date/hour values (as it should).  I just don't know how to include the actual reading/value so it shows up in the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make this a subquery and join on the appropriate ID?

eg,

```
select a.*, b.extracolumn
from othertable b
join ( ... ) a
on a.ID = b.ID
```

You're getting the errors because of the `group by` in your above query.  You shouldn't have the same problems if you join it, in its entirety, as a subquery.

Comment: Looks like this is the way I have to go.  MS Access doesn't like me joining two SELECT statements when I use a `TRANSFORM`...